# Mosby MVI - How to retry intents?

Tags: android, mosby

I'm using the Mosby MVI library for a demo app that performs simple CRUD operations on a Restful API using Retrofit2 in my Interactor.
I constructed the ViewStates very similar as in the sample App, containing Throwable when Retrofit responds with an error. In this case the `render()` function displays an error screen with a retry button.
When the retry button is clicked I want to re-emit the last item for the Intent that failed.

I would like to do add something like `retryWhen()` to the Intent, which of course is only triggered by `onError()`.

Is there a simple way of adding this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I resolved the issue myself using `combineLatest()`.
The retrySubject doesn't need to know the content of the previous intent.

```
class MyViewActivity extends MviActivity<MyView, MyViewState> implements MyView {
  PublishSubject<Boolean> retrySubject =  ... ; // fires on retry Button click
  ...

  @Override
  public Observable<String> searchIntent(){
    Observable<String> searchObservable =   RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView);
    return Observable.combineLatest(searchObservable,retrySubject(searchString, retryClicked) -> searchString);
  }
}
```

There is one thing to notice. combineLatest() only emits items when all Observables emitted a first item after subscribing to them. Thats why I need to initialize the retry after Mosby did its subscriptions.

```
@Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    retrySubject.onNext(true);
}
```

Please also view the answer from @sockeqwe at [Github](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/214)